# Spring Bean override

Tags: java, spring

I am struggling with a problem, I am having a component from a dependency annotated with @Component which implements some interfaces and overrides their methods. I must override the logic of one method (the method prints "first" or "second") of that component to match my requirements. I tried to: make a class annotated with @Primary and @Component which extends the parent component and I am overriding in it the method and when I @Autowired the parent into my class where is needed I am receiving that I get 2 calls, one from the first component and the second from my component, however I don't need the first call.
My Code looks like this:

```
//MainClass.java this class is read only
@Component
public class MainClass implements SomeThing {

   @Override
   public void myMethod() {
      Logger.info(this, "first");
   }
```

And my try to do it is:

```
@Primary
@Component
public OverMainClass extends MainClass {
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
       Logger.info(this, "second");
    }
}
```

Other class:

```
public class Other {

    @Autowired MainClass mainClass;

     ...

}
```

when I use `mainClass.myMethod` I must receive just only one call, "second" but I am receiving:
first
second
so, how can I disable the first call? Also, after disabling it I will need to re-enable the first call only, so again the second would not be present.
How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add the response you got?

Comment: @ray, first line: "First", second line: "Second"

Comment: Something must not be right. With such code it should work as expected. Can you share the complete code of `Other` class? Thanks.

Comment: @iftwMZ I don't think that is possible. Make sure you don't call super class' (`MainClass`) `myMethod`  method inside `OverMainClass` class `myMethod` method.

Comment: @iftwMZ  as @Joao  mentioned, share the full code for `Other` class as well.

Comment: @ray , there is no other code. Also i am not calling the super. I managed to get 2 calls, because there are two contexts:). Now it remains to implement only in that context.